# The expected value and variance

Tags: statistics

Question:

An electron microscope generates a large number of digital images. An image is stored with
probability $0.9$ in a format that requires $2$ Mbyte of space and with probability
$0.1$ in format with higher image quality which, however, requires 5 Mbyte file size. We suppose
independence between successive images. A data file that holds $100$ such images is called
a "block". Let $X$ be the number of Mbytes required to store a certain image and let
$Y$ be the corresponding size of a block.

a) Calculate the relative value and variance for $X$ and then for $Y$

For $X$, I used $E[X]=2\cdot 0.9 + 5 \cdot 0.1=2.3$

and then I calculated $V[X]=0.81$

and $E[Y]=2.3 \cdot 100 =230$

But how to calculate $V[Y]$?

Comment: Are you assuming independence?  If so, $V[A+B]=V[A]+V[B]$

Comment: @Henry, hmm, I do not know if I am understanding what you mean here, how is that supposed to help? since we do not know more that one term :)

Comment: You are adding up $100$ random variables and you know the distribution of each of them

Comment: @Henry, yes, thanks, I got it :), it should be $V[Y]=81$ Mb then.

How about "calculate  approximately the probability that a block is larger than 250 Mbytes."

I am thinking that I need to calculate the standard deviation first, but I do not know if I am thinking correct :)